# laravel two routes very similar on calls the other

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi there I have two routes that look identical except that one has an extra paramter called genre how do make them call their on routines and not have them mixed up.

```
Route::get('browse/{product_slug}', array(
    'as' => 'products.view_by_producttype', 
    function($slug)         
    {   
    }
))->where('product_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+');

Route::get('browse/{producttype_slug}/{genre_slug}', array(
    'as' => 'products.view_by_producttype_genre', 
    function($productype_slug, $genre_slug) 
    {       
    }   
))->where('producttype_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+')->where('genre_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+');
```

Upated Code and order:

```
Route::get('browse/{producttype_slug}', array(
    'as' => 'products.view_by_producttype', 
    function($producttype_slug)         
    { 
        $producttype = ProductTypes::where('slug', '=', $producttype_slug)->firstOrFail();      

        $items = DB::table('products')->join('productvariations', function($join) {
            $join->on('productvariations.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
        })->where('producttype_id', '=', $producttype->id)->paginate(1);

        return View::make('products.view_by_producttype')->with(compact('items', 'producttype'));

    }
))->where('producttype_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+');


Route::get('browse/{producttype_slug}/{genre_slug}', array(
    'as' => 'products.view_by_producttype_genre', 
    function($producttype_slug, $genre_slug) 
    { 
        $producttype = ProductTypes::where('slug', '=', $producttype_slug)->firstOrFail();

        $genre = GenreTypes::where('slug', '=', $genre_slug)->firstOrFail();

        $items = DB::table('products')->join('product_genretypes', function($join) {
            $join->on('product_genretypes.product_id', '=', 'products.id');             
        })->join('productvariations', function($join) {
            $join->on('productvariations.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
        })
        ->where('genretype_id', '=', $genre->id)
        ->where('producttype_id', '=', $producttype->id)
        ->paginate(1);

        return View::make('products.view_by_type_genre')->with(compact('items', 'producttype', 'genre'));

    }   
))->where('producttype_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+')->where('genre_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+');
```

Comment: You should show, what url you call that causes problem with your routing. Those above seems to be fine and work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap the order - have the Genre route defined first - like this:

```
Route::get('browse/{producttype_slug}/{genre_slug}', array(
    'as' => 'products.view_by_producttype_genre', 
    function($productype_slug, $genre_slug) 
    {       
    }   
))->where('producttype_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+')->where('genre_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+');

Route::get('browse/{product_slug}', array(
    'as' => 'products.view_by_producttype', 
    function($product_slug)         
    {   
    }
))->where('product_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+');
```

That way - if a route matches with a Genre route - it will be used first.

Otherwise it will default back to the normal Product route.

Comment: I tried that and it still ask me for genre variable

Comment: I just noticed - you have a small error in your code - change `function($slug)` to `function($product_slug)` in your product route. Not sure if that is the problem or not

Comment: Yeah I changed that but I'm still having the same problem what can I do

Comment: As @MarcinNabialek said - what url is causing this problem?

Comment: this one the browse/producttype_slug/genre_slug is always getting called instead of browse/produttype_slug

Comment: Yes - but give us an *actual* URL that is being called that causes the problem. From what we can see - the code should work

Comment: Unless you give us an *URL* that is being called that generates the error - we cant help any further.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/browse/dvd/  Undefined variable: genre (View: C:\Users\kirki_000\Documents\moviemagic\app\views\products\view_by_producttype.blade.php). And this one no error http://localhost:8000/browse/dvd/sci-fi

Comment: So the error says the problem is in the view file. It has nothing to do with your routes

Comment: Your view file `view_by_producttype.b‌​lade.php` has a variable called `$genre` which you have not set